# Autofill only non-empty cells in a column (excel) and skip filled cells

Tags: excel

i want to fill `A1:A200` with the number '12'. In this column, some cells are pre-filled with values e.g. A20 contains the number '3' etc. I want these pre-filled values to remain instead of being overwritten by autofill. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High light the entire range A1:A200, then press Control+G, click *Special*, check *Blanks*, then press *OK*.  Now that only the blank cells are highlighted, type the number 12 and then press Control+Enter.  This will enter the number 12 into all the blank cells.

Comment: wow this works perfectly. appreciate it friend!

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new column to column A. Type in cell A1

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1);12;A1)
```

or any other formula, which you want to apply to the existing data.

Copy down to row 200.

Select the new column range (B1:B200) copy and paste values to column A.

Delete Column B.